Jakarta CDI - Spring integration issue
I'm facing an issue in a Jakarta Faces app with a JSF bean trying to access a Spring bean (rewriting everything from Spring to CDI or vice-versa is out of scope of this question).
The CDI-Spring integration scheme was once well known and is described e.g. at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jsf. It relies on org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener and org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver. But now, with the newest versions of both Jakarta EE and Spring, I cannot get it working. The error I get is:
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E:
 An exception occurred while starting the application jakartaee-hello-world.
 The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException:
 org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:
 WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type HelloSpringBean with qualifiers @Default


Here is a tiny project to reproduce the issue (use the main branch):  https://github.com/rinnnn/experiments-cdi-spring-integration
If I comment out reference from the HelloJsfBean to the HelloSpringBean (see the feat/jsf-works-when-no-spring-bean-lookup branch in the repo), then it can be seen that the JSF app and page work, because it outputs in console:
[INFO] 17:46:51.406 [Default Executor-thread-15] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader -- Loaded 1 bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]


And when I compare output of this project in these two different branches, I see that the main branch contain no Spring logging before the error. Therefore it seems that the CDI somehow initializes before Spring context and errors out, why so and how to control this?
So it seems like I'm missing an important initialization part in this my demo project, but what is it?

Consider using joinfaces (link) in your project. It's enables JSF usage inside Spring Boot Application.
